# Why do I get an unexpected result with a ternary condition?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain to me this result please:

```
(trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}).has_key? :foo ? trad[:foo] : :foo
=> false
```

I expected it to return:

```
=> "Foo"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}).has_key? :foo ? trad[:foo] : :foo
```

is like:

```
(trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}).has_key? (:foo ? trad[:foo] : :foo)
```

`:foo ? trad[:foo] : :foo` is evaluated to `"Foo"` because `:foo` is treated as truth value.

`(trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}).has_key? "Foo"` yields `false` because there's no "Foo" key.

---

Use following (override precedence by surrounding parentheses) to get the expected result:

```
>> ((trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}).has_key? :foo) ? trad[:foo] : :foo
=> "Foo"
```

---

[`Hash#fetch(key, default)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) seems more appropriate:

```
>> {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}.fetch(:foo, :foo)
=> "Foo"
>> {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}.fetch(:baz, :baz)
=> :baz
```

Comment: Very clear. Thanks. (Hash#fetch is way better, thanks for that)

Comment: Nice call on `Hash#fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

For want of parenthesis the app was lost...

```
(trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}).has_key? :foo  ? trad[:foo] : :foo  # => false
(trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}).has_key?(:foo) ? trad[:foo] : :foo  # => "Foo"
```

I'd be careful writing code like this:

```
(trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"})
```

It's not idiomatic, so use:

```
trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"}
trad.has_key?...
```

The reason is, in times of panic, like at 2:45 AM when your coding partner gets a call about a system outage because he's on call, and dives into the code, that assignment could be hard to find.

In a code review I'd suggest something like this over the other:

```
trad = {foo: "Foo", bar:"Bar"} 
trad.has_key?(:foo) ? trad[:foo]
                    : :foo        # => "Foo"
```

Note: This only works on Ruby 1.9+.

That all said, I'd highly recommend using `fetch` as [recommended by @falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034598/128421).